# I can access docker.sock in Ubuntu, but not in Docker Desktop Windows

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, containers, docker-desktop

I want to set up CICD with docker and Jenkins on Windows with Docker Desktop and run docker commands from the Jenkins container. As I understand it, one way to do that is to expose the hosts docker daemon through the socket `docker.sock` to the Jenkins container. When I run the below `compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
    jenkins:
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      privileged: true
      user: root
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 50000:50000
      volumes:
        - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
```

with the command `docker compose up -d --build` in an Ubuntu VM with docker installed, the Jenkins container can run docker commands and everything seems to be working as intended. E.g. I can run `docker -v` inside the docker container (no `sudo` is needed).

But when I run the same `compose.yaml` on my Windows (Windows 10 Pro, 19045.3693) laptop with Docker Desktop (4.25.2), the Jenkins container can’t run docker commands. When I run `docker -v` inside the Jenkins container I get the error:

`/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found`

I have also installed `sudo` in the Jenkins VM and run `sudo docker -v` and get the error:

`sudo: docker: command not found`

More things I have tried is to use an extra slash `- //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. I have tried using named pipes but I think that is only relevant if you want to run a Windows container. I have tried to also bind mount `/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`, `//usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` and `/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`.

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` under volumes. This is needed for it to work in Ubuntu.

Edit: This post is about how to get it to work with Docker Desktop on Windows. All other posts doesn't mention Docker Desktop and seem to assume a Linux environment. Added clarification in first sentence. I don't think this question should be closed as it can illustrate the differences between e.g. Ubuntu VM and Docker Desktop.

Comment: There is no `/var/run/docker.sock` on windows. You need a named pipe: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/general/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api

Comment: Hi I have tried pipes. In the `compose.yaml` I replace `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` with: 
```
        - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
          target: /var/run/docker.sock
          type: npipe
```
and get error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "npipe": mount type unknown`.

I tried:
```
        - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
          target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
          type: npipe
```
with error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "npipe": mount type unknown`
And some other combos.

Comment: Difficult for proper formatting in comments but I added different variations of the answer here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5181

Comment: You are missing the `docker` command, not the Docker socket.  Bind-mounting the host's `docker` binary as you note only works on Linux and isn't espesically reliable.  The linked question describes a couple of standard approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the docker cli in the jenkins container similar to what @zsolt suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current jenkins/jenkins:lts image does not have docker client installed, you need to add it to an image and use it.

Interesting how and why your compose file works on ubuntu VM even though no docker cli installed in the container running from jenkins/jenkins:lts. Maybe previous jenkins/jenkins:lts image had it, and your docker engine on the ubuntu VM still has it and that is what used in your VM? This is why you should never use latest, lts, etc running tags/versions because the underlying software can and will change over time, you should pin your version like jenkins/jenkis:1.2.3-debian or something like this.

Anyways, this works on my Windows 10 machine with Docker Desktop for Windows:

Create this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.426.1-lts-jdk17

USER root

# Install Docker client cli
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88 && \
    add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce-cli

# create docker group 
RUN groupadd -g 1001 docker

# add jenkins user to docker group
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

**!!!Important!!!** You must use the same GUID for docker group in `RUN groupadd -g 1001 docker` command as it is on the wsl distro that you enabled the Docker Desktop WSL2 integration with and from where you issue your commands (docker build, docker run, etc). You can check the GUID on the wsl2 distro with `getent group docker`, for me it is 1001.

Note: Docker engine, the server, itself is not running in this wsl2 distro but rather it has it's own separate wsl2 distros with names docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data. You connect to this docker engine server with the docker client, the docker cli command.

Build the image: `docker build -f Dockerfile -t myjenkins:1.0.0-docker-cli .`

Run the container from the image from the wsl2 distro shell that you enabled Docker Desktop integration with: `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm -it myjenkins:1.0.0.-docker-cli sh`

Execute `docker ps` in the container shell and you will see your containers running on the host, including the container that you are currently inside.

**Be aware** that granting this kind of access to the container gives the jenkins user root level access on the host: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Comment: Thx. I was hoping to use it without installing any docker stuff in Jenkins container. I tried `jenkins/jenkins:2.426.1-lts-jdk17` in Ubuntu and it still worked. Note my edit about I forgot `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` in original post.

I don't understand how to check `getent group docker`? How do I run that inside Docker Desktop Virtual Machine?

Comment: you need to run the `getent group docker` command in the wsl2 linux distro, that you enabled Docker Desktop WSL2 integration in the DD GUI Settings. Check my update. Also you need to run the container with `docker run` from this WSL2 distro.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. When I run `wsl -l -v` in PowerShell to list all wsl instances running, I have "docker-desktop-data" and "docker-desktop", nothing else. If I log in to `wsl -d docker-desktop` there is no docker group here. In Docker Desktop GUI settings there is no option to choose a wsl2 linux distro. Did you perhaps already have a wsl2 linux distro installed on your computer before installing Docker Desktop and it recognized that and let you choose?

Comment: Just to add. I installed docker cli similar to your suggestion and it now works, thx (but running as root since I don't understand the user stuff, see my previous comment). I used this Dockerfile: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/#downloading-and-running-jenkins-in-docker

Comment: You can install linux distros with WSL2 and use them as linux machines. Docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data are special WSL2 distros, you are not supposed to log into them or modify anything in them, they are managed by Docker Dekstop. So what you can and should do is to install a WSL2 distro that you use as your local desktop (with no gui) and click the "Integrate wsl2" in Docker Desktop settings.

Comment: You can install ubuntu for example, with this command: `wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04` and get the list of installable distros: `wsl --list --online`. List installed distors: `wsl -l -v` You can enter you distros with `wsl -d distroname`